# Can a CHGCAR file be converted into a CIF file?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, cif, electron-density

A `.cif` file can be used for multiple purposes and is a more generic format to store atomic data.

Comment: In what situation would you only have a CHGCAR file? Surely, if you have a CHGCAR, then you also have a CONTCAR or POSCAR or vasprun.xml or some other file that contains structural information rather than the charge density. Edit: Based on your other questions, it looks like you want a CIF with charge density information, but that is not practical. The whole point of a charge density is that it is a volumetric property. If you just want point charges, then you can calculate partial atomic charges (e.g. using the Bader method).

Comment: @AndrewRosen The reason why I want a cif file conversion for my CHGCAR file is because I want to voxelize my CHGCAR data. Do you suggest any other method to make this happen?

Comment: You can use Vesta to do that. BUT I think that conversion is meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

While a CIF is not a suitable file format for handling volumetric charge density data, you may find Henkelman's chg2cube.pl [script](https://theory.cm.utexas.edu/vtsttools/scripts.html) to achieve what you're looking for. It will convert a VASP CHGCAR file into a [Cube](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/cube/) format, the latter of which many programs can also read and is fairly easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a follow up question: "But can a CUBE file be voxelized?" 

Discussion continued here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6235/can-a-file-in-the-gaussian-cube-format-be-voxelized